# Decision map with variable number of inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, decision-tree

I want to generate a model which recommends a type of movie. I have historical data to train the model, which has more than 20 features, like: age, gender, adress...

Nevertheless, the information used to make predictions contains a variable number of features, because many features are incomplete.
For example:

- For one person I have age, number of children and address.
- For other person I have phone number, name and age.

Is it possible to generate a machine learning model or a decision map (like decision tree) which uses a variable number of attributes and generate a list of possible outputs or posibilities for remaining attributes?
thanks

Comment: Is your data contains any label (such as: movie type of persons, ratings of some movie etc.)? If so, you can use supervised learning techniques like regression models, Bayes models, k-mean, etc.. Otherwise, you should use unsupervised learning (like Clustring, Neural Networks, Anomaly detection) to split your data into clusturs. My suggestion is to go with supervised learning if you are not an expert, because unsupervised learning is harder to apply and understand. You can check this example: https://www.kaggle.com/sherinclaudia/movie-rating-prediction

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use techniques to deal with missing values.

If in your dataset you know all the different attributes that can occur, just fill the missing values with a null value and the decision tree should be able to work around that.

I would also suggest looking at this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96458).

Comment: It is an option. But for empty features I was looking for an option in which the algoritm makes assumptions and give a result depending on those assuption. For example, if gender is empty the algoritm gives an output for the case in which  the gender is female and other result for the case in which the gender is male. Thanks